# Homebrew keeps telling me to update but it does not let me update

Tags: homebrew

```
$ brew doctor 

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
```

Then:

```
$ brew update 
$ brew --config

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9
HEAD: (none)
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7.3
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Xcode: 4.3.2
GCC-4.0: N/A
GCC-4.2: build 5666
LLVM: build 2335
Clang: 2.1 build 163
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11: /usr/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-249
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Which Perl:   /usr/bin/perl
Which Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Which Ruby:   /Users/luis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby
```

This happend in my other mac and I when I brew upgrade `brew outdated` nothing happened.
I am afraid this will do the same even dough is a new installation.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using **brew upgrade** did you tried using **brew update**. It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are differences between `brew update` and `brew upgrade`

`brew update`

Updates your local database of available (and no longer available) installable packages otherwise know in brew terminology as Formulae.

`brew upgrade`

Updates all the installed packages on your system currently. E.g. Upgrading PHP 5.3.20 to 5.3.21.

I don't see an error after you try to update, if you update and then run `brew doctor` again and it doesn't show the out of date error anymore then you are fully up to date.